# type () does not conform to protocol anyobject

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to confirm submission before leaving the view controller :

however I am getting this error :

```
type () does not conform to protocol anyobject
```

here is the line where the error appears :

```
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.target = self.validateBeforeBack("back", completion: { (bool) -> () in
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    })
```

**UDATE** :
So the solution was to change *target* to *action* and to put the function call inside `Selector()`

that is :

```
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.action = Selector(self.validateBeforeBack("back", completion: { (bool) -> () in
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }))
```

Comment: put your delegate method @optional.

Comment: @ChetanPrajapati I am not using delegate methods for this issue , Can u explain what func R U meaning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear what `validateBeforeBack()` returns, since you did not provide it. From the error, I assume it returns `()` (i.e. "void" or "nothing"). You can't assign the result of that to a property.

I assume what you really wanted to do was call this function when the button is pressed. That's not how target/action buttons work. See `Target-Action` in [Concepts in Objective-C Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Target-Action/Target-Action.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH12). You need to set `target` to the object you want the message sent to, and `action` to the selector you want to send.

Comment: What should the closure return to be accepted as a target or an action ?

Comment: A closure is neither a target nor an action. Have you read the linked introduction to target-action patterns in Cocoa? The function would need to return an object that responds to the action selector. Usually the target is the view controller and the action is the method you want to call.

Answer (score 2):

1. `popViewControllerAnimated(_:)` has a return type of `UIViewController?`, however the closure argument to your function `validateBeforeBack(_:completion:)` has a `Void` return type (the implementation of your `validateBeforeBack(_:completion:)` function, or else the closure that you pass to it, should be adjusted to take this into account)
2. make sure that your `validateBeforeBack(_:completion:)` function actually has a return type (since it is the value in an assignment)